# How do I achieve this with vim cindent?

Tags: c++, vim, indentation

If I write the following code in vim at the moment

```
const SomeType & some_function (<ENTER>
```

then vim will continue the next line at an indent of two tabs. I want it to indent the next line with only one tab.

I know [cindent](http://vimdoc.sourceforge.net/htmldoc/options.html#%27cinoptions%27) exists, but I can't work out what [syntax](http://vimdoc.sourceforge.net/htmldoc/options.html#%27cinkeys%27) will make this happen.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`:help cinoptions-values`

```
(N    When in unclosed parentheses, indent N characters from the line
      with the unclosed parentheses.  Add a 'shiftwidth' for every
      unclosed parentheses.  When N is 0 or the unclosed parentheses
      is the first non-white character in its line, line up with the
      next non-white character after the unclosed parentheses.
      (default 'shiftwidth' * 2).

        cino=                     cino=(0 >
          if (c1 && (c2 ||          if (c1 && (c2 ||
                      c3))                     c3))
              foo;                      foo;
          if (c1 &&                 if (c1 &&
                  (c2 || c3))           (c2 || c3))
             {                         {
```

Comment: Thank you for finding the relevant doc but I don't understand it *AT ALL*! The examples appear to be indented randomly to me, I can't map that to the `cino` string in any way :-(

Comment: Also, how does it change when tabs are/aren't expanded?

Comment: You basically want to pass `(1` to the cinoptions.

Comment: Yeah, just type `:set cinoptions=(1` and give it a try, maybe play around with different values until you get the right result.  If it helps, I have `cinoptions=g0,:0,(0,w1,Ws` which left-aligns class scope declarations and case statements in their respective blocks, aligns run-on lines with the opening parenthises (like the right column example above), etc.